# Reading double from console

Tags: c#, string, console, double

How can I read double value for example 0.3 from Console? When I type something with .X like mentioned before 0.3 it throws Exception.

So far I've tried something like that:

```
Console.WriteLine("Type x: ");
double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? You get any exception or error message? What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: System Format Exception.

Comment: Use `Double.Parse` or `Double.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToDouble`, it gives you a lot more control.

Comment: You need to provide a good code example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Show _exactly_ the string you are actually passing to the `ToDouble()` method. And answer the first comment about `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. Because `Convert.ToDouble("0.3")` works just fine on my machine.

Comment: Double.Parse throws an exception too. Everything is fine as long as I type int value in console, for instance 3. Exception is thrown when double value is typed.

Comment: The code is as long as You can see, I just want to read double value from console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Convert.ToDouble`(string)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,d98fcd7819f63d0f) method uses `Double.Parse` with your `CurrentCulture` settings. Here how it's [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,d98fcd7819f63d0f);

```
public static double ToDouble(String value)
{
     if (value == null)
         return 0;
     return Double.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

And this [Double.Parse](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,73cc31e0b47fd637) implemented as;

```
public static double Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    return Parse(s, NumberStyles.Float| NumberStyles.AllowThousands, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
}
```

As you can see, this parsing operation will succeed *only* if your `NumberStyles.Float| NumberStyles.AllowThousands` matches with your `CurrentCulture` settings.

I strongly suspect your `CurrentCulture`'s [`NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) is not dot (`.`) And that's why your code throws `FormatException`.

You can 2 options; use a culture that have `NumberDecimalSeparator` as a `.` like `InvariantCulture` or [`.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your `CurrentCulture` and set it's `NumberDecimalSeparator` to `.`.

```
Console.WriteLine("Type x: ");
double x = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
Console.WriteLine("Type x: ");
double x = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), culture);
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed statement. Yes indeed, my CUrrenctCulture's seperator is ',' :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use TryParse:

```
Console.Write("Type x: ");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
double value;

while (!double.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.Any,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value))
{
    Console.Write("{0} is not a double. Please try again: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("Thank you! {0} is a double", value);
```